# Number of instruments in GMM (using pgmm in R)

Tags: r, instrumental-variables, generalized-moments

Number of instruments used in GMM model (`pgmm` function in R)
I performed a GMM (Generalized Methods of Moments) analysis in R using the `plm` package.

I included additional external variables in my model. However, since the model also uses internal instruments (lagged dependent variables), I am not sure how many instruments there are in total.

Is there any way how I can calculate them or is there a function in R that provides the value?

Comment: Questions solely about how software works are
[off-topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) 
here, but you may have a real statistical question buried 
here. You may want to edit your question to clarify the 
underlying statistical issue. You may find that when you 
understand the statistical concepts involved, the 
software-specific elements are self-evident or at least 
easy to get from the documentation.